# Forward Fill with Reference to ID column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, ffill

Suppose I have a dataframe as follows:

```
Roll No  |  Name  |  School  |  Year  |  Total Marks  |  Previous Marks
------------------------------------------------------------------------
1001     |  abc   |   iisr   |  2005  |      595      |      NaN
1002     |  amr   |   iisd   |  2005  |      599      |      NaN
1001     |  abc   |   iisr   |  2006  |      NaN      |      580
1003     |  def   |   hmms   |  2005  |      600      |      575
1002     |  amr   |   iisd   |  2006  |      NaN      |      590
1004     |  ghi   |  aaiisr  |  2005  |      580      |      NaN
1005     |  jkl   |   ups    |  2005  |      599      |      500
1001     |  abc   |   iisr   |  2007  |      597      |      NaN
1002     |  amr   |   iisd   |  2007  |      600      |      NaN
1005     |  jkl   |   ups    |  2006  |      NaN      |      503
1006     |  mno   |   iisr   |  2005  |      NaN      |      480
1001     |  abc   |   iisr   |  2008  |      NaN      |      575
1007     |  pqr   |   kms    |  2005  |      NaN      |      575
1002     |  amr   |   iisd   |  2008  |      NaN      |      499
```

I want to forward-fill the columns `Total Marks` and `Previous Marks` such that for a particular `Roll No`, the null values get replaced with their previous occurrence.

For example, in the `Total Marks` column, the Roll No 1001 has a value of `595` in 2005, a `NaN` in 2006, `597` in 2007, and a `NaN` in 2008. I want the null value present for 1001 in the year 2006 to be replaced by its previously filled score (i.e. score of 2005), and the null value of the year 2007 to be replaced with the score value in the year 2008. If previous value is not found, then let it be as `NaN`. The same logic to be applied for `Previous Marks` column.

My final dataframe after forward-filling in the above mentioned format should be as follows:

```
Roll No  |  Name  |  School  |  Year  |  Total Marks  |  Previous Marks
------------------------------------------------------------------------
1001     |  abc   |   iisr   |  2005  |      595      |      NaN
1002     |  amr   |   iisd   |  2005  |      599      |      NaN
1001     |  abc   |   iisr   |  2006  |      595      |      580
1003     |  def   |   hmms   |  2005  |      600      |      575
1002     |  amr   |   iisd   |  2006  |      599      |      590
1004     |  ghi   |  aaiisr  |  2005  |      580      |      NaN
1005     |  jkl   |   ups    |  2005  |      599      |      500
1001     |  abc   |   iisr   |  2007  |      597      |      580
1002     |  amr   |   iisd   |  2007  |      600      |      590
1005     |  jkl   |   ups    |  2006  |      599      |      503
1006     |  mno   |   iisr   |  2005  |      NaN      |      480
1001     |  abc   |   iisr   |  2008  |      597      |      575
1007     |  pqr   |   kms    |  2005  |      NaN      |      575
1002     |  amr   |   iisd   |  2008  |      600      |      499
```

I referred several solutions in StackOverflow, GeeksForGeeks, and the pandas documentation also for the pandas `ffil()` function, but wasn't of much help. Any ideas how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Groupby, ffill should do I think.

```
df[['Total_Marks','Previous_Marks']]=df.groupby('Roll_No')[['Total_Marks','Previous_Marks']].fillna(method='ffill')
```